# Condensing a repeated Selection and Number Formatting

Tags: vba, excel

I'm working with the following code:

```
Private Sub FormatAsNumbers()
    Dim rRngs As Range
    LastRow = Worksheets("Table").Range("C4").End(xlDown).Row

    Range("C4:" & "C" & LastRow).Select
    Selection.NumberFormat = "#,##0"

    Range("e4:" & "e" & LastRow).Select
    Selection.NumberFormat = "#,##0"

    Range("g4:" & "g" & LastRow).Select
    Selection.NumberFormat = "#,##0"


    Range("I4:" & "I" & LastRow).Select
    Selection.NumberFormat = "#,##0"


    Range("K4:" & "K" & LastRow).Select
    Selection.NumberFormat = "#,##0"


    Range("M4:" & "M" & LastRow).Select
    Selection.NumberFormat = "#,##0"

End Sub
```

I'm trying to find a way to bring together the different columns (down to the last row) and format them appropriately without having to repeat each column separately.

Comment: You can get rid of the `.select` and just do the ranges.numberformat

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like what you need is `Application.Union`. You don't need to select the range to apply number formatting as you use it, though that may be helpful for other things you need to do. The formula condenses down to:

```
Application.Union(Range("C4:" & "C" & lastrow), Range("e4:" & "e" & lastrow),_
Range("g4:" & "g" & lastrow), Range("I4:" & "I" & lastrow),_
Range("K4:" & "K" & lastrow), Range("M4:" & "M" & lastrow)).NumberFormat = "#,##0"
```

You might want to add some line spacing in, but that should do the trick.

Comment: Yeah I figured a union would have been the way to go, didn't know if there was a work-around so that each range didn't have to be added individually.